# Recorded video is the wrong orientation

Tags: android, camera

I'm using `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` to rotate the camera.

This successfully changes the camera preview, but not the actual "camera" so the recorded video is still sideways. Is their a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this might help you

`mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()`

Comment: Thank you, I got it working eventually and forgot to post an update, but yer this is how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Video stream is never rotated - it is recorded as it comes. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29): "*Set the clockwise rotation of preview display in degrees. This affects the preview frames and the picture displayed after snapshot.*"

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a way to rotate the video after recording. In my app, I upload the video afterwards to Youtube and would prefer not all uploaded videos to be sidewards.

Comment: I got no exact pointer but looking for "rotate video java" would lead you somewhere, yet I'd like to point out that this is rather heavy computing thing as you need to recode whole video stream. Not sure if it is good thing to do on mobile (if you plan do so), due to lack of computing power and power hunger it may generate.