# Custom Video Recording Orientation

Tags: android, video, camera, recording

When I record video using MediaRecorder in portrait mode, video recorded in landscape mode ,

I have tried for mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90); and mServiceCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

There's [not a good way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166919/752320) for older API levels.

If you're using >=14, you can use  [Media Effect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html) calls to change the orientation. Instructions for its use can be found in that link. You'll need a valid OpenGL context to use with it, so it's slightly more complicated than a simple camera app.

You'll want to use [`EFFECT_ROTATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html#EFFECT_ROTATE), most likely.